# Firebase Cloud Function prints 'undefined' when reading a node in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

This is the first part of a function that will trigger a notification when a new Message is created in Firebase Database.

I am getting the following output on the console when I try to print a value from the datasnapshot. Am I missing something here?

```
fromId undefined
```

This is my DB structure:

```
"messages" : {
    "-LJrd_EGOqbv0XqeNoJp" : {
      "fromId" : "dBQd541pxlRypR7l1WT2utKVxdX3",
      "message" : "hey ",
      "timeStamp" : 1.534236972096062E9,
      "toId" : "dBQd541pxlRypR7l1WT2utKVxdX2"
    }
}
```

This is my notifyNewMessage Firebase Cloud Function

```
exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/{message}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const messageSnap = snap.val(); 

  const from_Id = messageSnap["fromId"];

  console.log('fromId', from_Id);

});
```

Comment: What does `messageSnap` look like? What happens when you do `console.log(messageSnap)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is triggering on the `message` property right now, so it only has access to *that* specific value.

To get access to all properties of the new message, trigger one level higher:

```
exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const messageSnap = snap.val(); 

  const from_Id = messageSnap["fromId"];
  console.log('fromId', from_Id);

  const message = messageSnap.message; // you can also use . notation
  console.log('message', message);

});
```